# How can I do input tags in C# with DevExpress WinForms?

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm using Devexpress win-ui forms for desktop and I want to implement search bar like [this](http://betaweb.github.io/inputTags-jQuery-plugin/):
[image: Screenshot]
Is there any way to do like this plugin in DevExpress `WinForms`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does that jQuery plugin have to do with DevExpress?

Comment: I'm using Devexpress win-ui forms for desktop and I want to implement search bar like this.

Comment: Well you've linked to a jQuery plugin, which is clearly designed for the web... so if you're writing a Windows Forms app, that's not going to be appropriate. If you're looking for a specific piece of functionality in Windows forms, you should make your question reflect that - along with what you've tried.

Comment: you might want to add a screenshot to the actual look of the tags you want to use instead of linking to a big documentation page of a different product.

Comment: And the specific piece of functionality you're looking for, rather than just "do like this".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `WinForms` platform there is `TokenEdit` control.
[image]

More info you can find in DevExpress Documentation topic «[Token Edit Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17088)».